# Exporting derby database and jsf project inside netbeans to another computer with netbeans

Tags: netbeans, entity, derby

I used netbeans' automatic generation of entity classes from database and automatic generation of JSF pages from entity classes to build a simple CRUD web application.

I used glassfish server and java db.

Now I want to move the application to another computer with a separate install of netbeans.

How to move the database and netbeans project files to another computer with netbeans installed?

Comment: The "application" is code. The "database" is data. The "netbeans project files" are configuration settings. These 3 separate things typically have 3 separate treatments. Is this a 1-time migration (why?), or is this part of a larger build process that will routinely develop work on one machine and try to deploy it elsewhere?

Comment: 1-time migration because i built the project at home and i want to build upon it at work.